# Amount of free transactions in a month (Java exercise)

Tags: java

I have this exercise on my book that says:

> Now make a more complex change. The bank will allow a fixed number
>   of free transactions (deposits or withdrawals) every month, and charge
>   for transactions exceeding the free allotment. The charge is not levied
>   immediately but at the end of the month.

Now, i know that i have to check the amount of free transactions made that month and reset them every month but i really don't know how i could do that.

This is my code so far:

```
package BankAccount;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

/** A bank account has a balance that can be changed by deposits and withdrawals.  */

public class BankAccount {

    /** Constructs a bank account with 0 balance. */
    public BankAccount() {
        balance = 0;
    }

    /** Constructs a bank account with a given balance. 
     * @param initialBalance the initial balance */
    public BankAccount(double initialBalance, double initialFee) {
        balance = initialBalance;
        fee = initialFee;
    }

    /** Deposit money into the bank account. 
     * @param amount the amount to deposit */
    public void deposit(double amount) {
        double newBalance = balance + amount;
        balance = newBalance - fee;
    }

    /** Withdraws money from the bank account.
     * @param amount the amount to withdraw */

    public void withdraw(double amount) {
        double newBalance = balance - amount;
        balance = newBalance - fee;
    }

    /** Gets the current balance of the bank account.
     * @return balance the current balance */
    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    /** Adds interest to the balance of the bank account.
     * @param rate the rate for the interest rate  */
    public void addInterest(double rate) {
        double interestRate = rate;
        double amountToAdd = balance * interestRate / 100;
        balance = balance + amountToAdd;
    }

    /** Sets the fee
     * @param feeAmount the amount to remove
     */

    public void setFee(double feeAmount) {
        fee = feeAmount;
    }

    /** Sets the month
     * @param month the number of the month
     */
    public void setMonth(int month) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    }

    private double balance;
    private double fee;
    private Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

}
```

Comment: you'll do it keeping some state to your instantiated class, using attributes

Comment: I see, but shouldn't the program check what month is it and then eventually reset the transaction count?

Comment: This sounds like a month end job. When ever a bank account applies the fees if any for that account for that month, just reset the count to zero as a last statement. Hope you are keeping the transaction count per account in database.